# Blazor Server Side breakpoints are bound but not being hit

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-7.0

I'm running a Blazor server side project with .NET 7 in VS Preview. By breakpoints are bound, but they do not get hit. Everything I search talks about fixing unbound breakpoints but that is not my issue here. I tried deleting the .vs folder. How do I force VS to hit the breakpoints that are bound?

Comment: We can't guess what's going on with *no* code. Blazor Server is server-side ASP.NET Core that does some extra stuff. The same debugger that's used in ASP.NET Core web apps is used in Blazor Server. If breakpoints aren't hit, the most likely reason is that the code isn't being called. Or the *source* doesn't match the actual application.

Comment: I'm launching it right from Visual Studio so I don't see how the code could be different, and it definitely should be hitting the code. I tried in multiple places.

Comment: Which probably means *that* code isn't called. Or it could mean that there's a compilation error and the debug session started with older binaries. You need to clean `bin` and `obj` to remove the binaries, not `.vs`

Comment: Are you sure to use the `Start (F5)` and not the `Start without debugging (Ctrl + F5)`? Filled play instead of not filled one?

Comment: Also make sure you are compiling to Debug and not Release.